# Can I build and distribute app to apple store without Xcode UI?

Tags: ios, xcode, distribute

I want to auto build object-c code and distribute app to apple store,by hudson and some scripts.
can I do that? I know xcodebuild can build code by command line. but I don't know whether I can distribute app by command line?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't upload the app automatically by a script... Few forms needs to be submitted with Application info in iTunesconnect.. and Apple don't  provide anything to automatize that ..

Comment: thanks! if I use $299 developer account, I can shared test version app by self, no need apple store? is right?

Comment: you can self distribute if you have $299 enterprise developer account

Comment: you still can put it on cydia or other alternative stores for jail break devices